# Localization translation for Google Analytics API data

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the [Google APIs PHP client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), trying to get data out of the Google Analytics API.

When I request f.e. ga:city as a dimension, I get a list of all the city names.
The city names are however in English, and not in the local language.

Is it possible to set a locale?
Or is it even not possible with Google API in general?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics API returns data in English only.   You will have to translate them yourself.

**Tip**: If you are going to do some kind of translation I would use [ga:countryISOcode](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network&jump=ga_countryisocode) or maybe [ga:cityid](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network&jump=ga_cityid) instead. They are more acturate then ga:city

Post about [Geo networking dimensions](http://www.daimto.com/the-new-geo-network-dimensions-in-google-analytics/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the locale as follows, however in your specific case this will still get city names in English only. :(

```
 // Load Google Charts for the Japanese locale.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart'], 'language': 'ja'});
```

According to Google documentation:

> Locales are used to customize text for a country or language,
>   affecting the formatting of values such as currencies, dates, and
>   numbers.
>
> By default, the Google Chart libraries are loaded with the "en"
>   locale. You can override this default by explicitly specifying a
>   locale in the loading parameters.
>
> To load a chart formatted for a specific locale, use the language
>   parameter like so.

(Source: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale)